# How to disable unchecked checkbox in tree tableview column in Javafx

Tags: checkbox, javafx, binding

I have a treetable column, to which I am adding checkbox as below

```
isPrimary.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn<String, Boolean>, TreeTableCell<String, Boolean>>() {
            @Override
            public TreeTableCell<String, Boolean> call(TreeTableColumn<String, Boolean> param) {
                    return new LiveCheckBoxTreeTableCell();
            }
        });
```

I am writing my own checkbox as below

```
public class LiveCheckBoxTreeTableCell extends TreeTableCell<String,Boolean>{
    private final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
       private ObservableList<CheckBox> selectedCheckBoxes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        private ObservableList<CheckBox> unselectedCheckBoxes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
        public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else{

                setGraphic(checkBox);
                 if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                     selectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
                 } else {
                     unselectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
                 }
                checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                      @Override
                      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean, Boolean aBoolean2) {
                          if (aBoolean2) {
                                unselectedCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox);
                                selectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
                            } else {
                                selectedCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox);
                                unselectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
                            }

                      }
                    });


            }
        }
    }
```

When I check one checkbox other checkbox in the `isPrimary` column should be disabled.
But the Checkbox I check and uncheck will get disabled. Others will remain enabled.
Any Javafx please help me to disable unchecked checkbox and enable all checkbox when I uncheck any checked checkbox.

Comment: Why you don't try binding between items of lists?

Comment: I tried binding checkbox like below  but it just disables checked box not unchecked box                                           
                              @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, Boolean aBoolean,
      Boolean aBoolean2) {
     if (aBoolean2) {
           checkBox.disableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty().not());

     } else {
      checkBox.selectedProperty().bind(checkBox.disabledProperty().not());
     }